# c++ 2d array of unique_ptr objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to create a simple 2D array or vector of SFML's Sprite objects.  I have tried many different ways and always end up getting errors or just an empty vector.

I have tried

```
// first x
for ( int c = 0; c < w ; ++c)
{
    vector<unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>> col;
    map.push_back(std::move(col));

    // then y
    for ( int r = 0; r < h ; ++r) {
        map[c].push_back(unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>(new sf::Sprite()));
    }
}
```

and

```
unique_ptr<sf::Sprite[0][0]> map;
...
map.reset(unique_ptr<sf::Sprite[0][0]>(new sf::Sprite[w][h]));
```

Overall, I'm just not successful at making a 2d smart pointer object array and was wondering if someone could help.  Sorry if I didnt include enough detail,  this is my first post to stack overflow, so please be gentle :)

EDIT:  Let me give some more detail on this, sorry.  So i'm making this 2d array in a factory type class which is basically a singleton.  So I need this 2d array to persist after it has been created and left the stack etc.

Comment: Then make it a [static] member variable or define it in a namespace.

Comment: Note: you should not create a 2D array of sprites. You should create a 1D array of sprites of `width*height` length, which you *access* like a 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `map` as a pointer to a multi-dimensional array and trying insert objects of type `std::vector<>` into it. Instead you can use a vector (of vectors in this case) and eliminate the allocation of the array and simplify it in the process.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace sf { class Sprite {}; }

int main()
{
    const int w = 5;
    const int h = 5;

    // vector of vectors of Sprites is what you're looking for
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>>>   map;

    // first x
    for ( int c = 0; c < w ; ++c)
    {
        // No need to access via index of c. Just append to the column vector itself.
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>> col;

        // then y
        for ( int r = 0; r < h ; ++r)
        {
             col.push_back(std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>(new sf::Sprite()));
        }

        // Now add the column vector.
        map.push_back(std::move(col));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it the shortest way to make 2d array of `std::unique_ptr`? I came up with the same but I have a strong feeling that something better should exist. Nothing more idiomatic?